# HQL query with null parameter, is it possible?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write an HQL query like so :

`select distinct new com.myproject.entities.MyPerson(person.firstName , person.lastName, person.age, address.streetName) from Person person, Address address`

I'd like to fetch BOTH the instances of MyObject where the age is null along with the ones where age is not null. I've tried the following, which did not work :
`select distinct new com.myproject.entities.MyObject(person.name, person.lastName, null, address.streetName) from Person person, Address address`

I've also created a constructor that only takes the firstName, lastName and streetName params, and tried to write the following query :
`select distinct new com.myproject.entities.MyObject(person.name, person.lastName, person.age, address.streetName), new com.myproject.entities.MyObject(person.name, person.lastName, address.streetName) from Person person, Address address`

That one did not work either due to a syntax error (the ',').

At this point I'm not sure how to do it. Is it even possible ?